# Invalid Authenticity Token Error for a genuine request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a customer who has trouble sending in a registration form on our web site. The form has worked for several other customers, so I don't think the form itself has any errors. The POST request the customer sends gets ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken error.

I checked from our logs that the customer opened the form, filled it and sent it in less than 5 minutes, so the token should not have expired. But each time before the customer opens the form page there are 2-4 requests to the same form from Amazon IP addresses. That seems weird.

The customer is not a tech person so he cannot provide much information about their Internet setup. What I could tell to the customer to do so that they could send the form successfully?

Comment: Did you ask him to try clear cookies and sessions and try again?
Also, you can ask him to fill the form with incognito

Comment: I now asked him to try a different browser. Have not yet heard back from him after that.

Comment: maybe the cookie or sessions problem is cause for this and I think he can fix the issue by changing browser or purging cookies